# How could I grep twice in one pass?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, grep

Is there a way to avoid doing `grep` two times in the file and just populate the
variables in one pass? The file is small so it is not that a big deal I 
was just wondering if I could do it in one pass

```
FIRST_NAME=$(grep "$customer_id" customer-info|cut -f5 -d,)
LAST_NAME=$(grep "$customer_id" customer-info|cut -f6 -d,)
```

Comment: How are the variables used later in the code? It may be that they are not needed at all.

Comment: @Kusalananda _Why would you want to do X?  Don't do X.  Do Y._

Answer (score 14):

You could grep once and split twice using shell string substitution:

```
NAME=$(grep "$customer_id" customer-info | cut -f5,6 -d,)
FIRST_NAME=${NAME%,*}
LAST_NAME=${NAME#*,}
```

Or, with bash, using process substitution:

```
IFS=, read FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME < <(grep "$customer_id" customer-info | cut -f5,6 -d,)
```

`read` will split input on `IFS` and assign the first value to `FIRST_NAME` and the rest to `LAST_NAME`. Using process substitution and redirection `< <(...)` allows you to pass the output of `grep ... | cut ...` to `read` without using a subshell.

Comment: This depends on the fields being sequential. What if it changed to 5 and 7?

Comment: @Jim Then don't do the `cut` operation after the `grep` and use `read` to break the string by specifying a custom `IFS` and grab the columns you need from an array.

Comment: @Jim it doesn't. Since you can specify whichever fields you want with `-f` - `-fm,n` is a list of fields, not a range - this works fine even if the fields aren't next to each other. It does require them to be in order, but if the order is reversed then just swap the variables.

Comment: Nitpick: process substitution does use a subshell -- but it does the `read` in the main shell thus the variable setting is not lost, while a pipeline `something | read var var` can do the `read` in a subshell depending on your shell variant and sometimes options/modes.

Comment: @dave yes, of the course the point about subshells is only for the `read` command, not the `grep ... | cut` pipeline, which is always in a subshell in bash because it's a pipeline.

Comment: Isn't your change of IFS affecting subsequent operations here

Comment: @jas no, since `read` is a built-in, it's only set locally for the built-in's execution. If `read` were a wrapper function around the actual built-in, though, it will depend on the shell and the way the function was defined and other things

Answer (score 4):

You could use `awk` in combination with bash `read`:

```
read -r FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME <<< $(awk -F, -v cid="$customer_id" '$0~cid{print $5,$6}' customer-info)
```

`-F` tells awk to use the comma as field delimiter

`-v` sets the awk variable `cid` to the shell variable `$customer_id`

If the line matches the `$customer_id`, awk will print the 5th and 6th fields and these will get assigned the variables `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME`.

If first name ($5) ever contains space (example: a,b,c,d,Sarah Jane,Smith) add `-v OFS=,` to have `awk` output comma between fields and prefix `read` with `IFS=,` to have it split at comma.

Additionally `awk` can search in only a particular field like `'$3~cid{print..}'` -- and can match that *entire* field by `'$3~"^"cid"$"{print...}'` if that matters for your ids.

Comment: Doesn't work as written; edit proposed, with additions since I'm at it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Your changes are valid one. Thanks. However I do not see any difference between the previous version having `/.../` and your version `$0~...`. Can you also explain what did not work for you?

Comment: If you just use `cid` as the pattern, awk does not match the line against the regexp cid -- it only checks if the variable cid is nonempty, whilch is always true, so awk outputs all lines, not the single line you wanted. That's why you need `$0 ~ cid` -- match the line ($0) against the regexp in cid.

Comment: When you write a literal regexp `/regexp/ {action}` the slashes are not part of the regexp, they are special syntax that says there _is_ a regexp. When you put the regexp in a variable if you include a slash that slash is a _data_ character that must match the input data (here, adjacent to the customer_id value) which it almost certainly won't (although conceivably the OP could have data that always has slashes around the customer_id values).

Answer (score 4):

The simplest would be to get the entire record into a variable and then use `cut` on that.

```
RECORD=$(grep "$customer_id" customer-info)
FIRST_NAME=$(echo "$RECORD"|cut -f5 -d,)
LAST_NAME=$(echo "$RECORD"|cut -f6 -d,)
```

Also personally I would recommend using a more specific regular expression. If your customer IDs are always at the beginning of the line, you can write `grep '^'"$customer_id"` instead of `grep "$customer_id"` to require the match to be at the beginning of the line. Otherwise you might pick up records where text matching the customer ID happens to appear elsewhere in the record.

Answer (score 2):

Small file, big file. One habit I have is to always eliminate disk IO as much as I can. One way to do this is to push the file into an array. Of course this requires the env $IFS is set appropriately for the file but eliminates the IO.

`data=( $(cat customer-info) )`

Then you can cherry pick from that...

`FIRST_NAME=$(echo "${data[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep "$customer_id" | cut -f5 -d,)`

Another method might be to assign only those two bits desired to an array like so...

`data=( $(grep "${customer_id}" customer-info | cut -d, -f5,6) )`

Comment: -1 for slurping the entire data set into a Bash variable even though the filter is known beforehand.

Comment: How do you know the op doesn't require additional data? Assume nothing, eliminate as much overhead io as possible for future operations. Thanks for the concern and opinion however

Comment: reminds me of the guy who dumped two SQL tables into a variale each, then cross referenced them on a one to many field, then selected the single entry they needed. 
But I didn't know ASP, so who was I to criticise?

Comment: Weee,  this was the most constructive dialog I have ever engaged in. Someone has poisoned the well.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers all store the output in memory (in a variable) and replay it twice. This is an issue if you want to make a generic wrapper that can take an arbitrarily large input and perform two tasks on it. Instead, the output stream can be duplicated and streamed into two commands.

In my case, the purpose is to filter both the header (first line) and a specific (set of) line(s) in an output stream that may be arbitrarily long. A simple example would be displaying disk space usage:

```
$ df -h | tee >(head -1 >&2) | grep '/$'
Filesystem    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1     202G  145G   57G  72% /
```

Replace `df -h` with the command you want to use, and replace `head -1` and `grep '/$'` with the two commands you want to apply to it. The output of both will be displayed in your terminal, though it may be that the output of the former command is displayed after the latter.

How does this work?

- The program `tee` "[copies] standard input to each [argument], and also to standard output." So it can send output on stdin to both stdout and stderr by using `command | tee /dev/stderr`.
- The `command >(command2)` syntax is replaced by an argument by bash, so `command /dev/fd/63` will be executed. When `command` tries to write to `/dev/fd/63`, it will end up in the input (stdin) of `command2`. This is called process substitution (see `man bash`).
- Since `tee` writes both to the argument (we pass a command substitution as an argument) and to stdout, we can just add another pipe and do another command. So now we have `command | tee >(command2) | command3`.
- Finally, since command2 will output to stdout, and stdout is piped to `command3`, we would (in my example) be grepping the header line. That is not what we want: we want to display it. Since we are not piping stderr through, redirecting the output to stderr is an easy way of displaying it in our terminal, i.e. we add `>&2`, resulting in `command | tee >(command2 >&2) | command3`.

There is one problem: the output may be in any order. Depending on cosmic rays, we might see either the above or the following:

```
$ df -h | tee >(head -1 >&2) | grep '/$'
/dev/sda1     202G  145G   57G  72% /
Filesystem    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
```

A hacky but reliable way to fix this (instead of some over-engineered way that is not hacky) is to add a short sleep to the second command; something like:

```
$ df -h | tee >(head -1 >&2) | sleep 1; grep '/$'
```

But wait, this breaks the second command (`grep`), because now the output is piped from `tee` to `sleep` and `grep` will be waiting for input indefinitely. To fix that, we add a subshell:

```
$ df -h | tee >(head -1 >&2) | (sleep 0.01; grep '/$')
Filesystem    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1     202G  145G   57G  72% /
```

Now the output is not redirected to `grep` but to our subshell. Since `sleep` does not read from it (it does not consume the stream), it is still available for `grep` to read. Now it works reliably so long as `head` outputs within 0.01 seconds (plus a bit of overhead on the grep side), which is a fair bet on a modern system and short enough not to be noticeable to the user.

Since I wanted to make something that takes both the header and the output of some command, we can generalize this to:

```
function grabheader {
    tee >(head -1 >&2)
}
```

Since the `tee` command in the function will just read from stdin and output to stdout, this does the same as our earlier out-of-order command when you use it as `df -h | grabheader | grep '/$'`. But since we want it to be in-order, we need to delay sending it down the stdout:

```
function grabheader {
    tee >(head -1 >&2) | (sleep 0.01; cat)
}
```

`cat` here just makes sure that whatever is passed to the stdin will make its way onto the stdout again. By passing no arguments and adding no redirections, it will do just that. Usage:

```
$ df -h | grabheader | grep '/$'
Filesystem    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1     202G  145G   57G  72% /
```

---

Of course, in the particular case of `df`, this can be done much simpler:

```
$ df -h /
Filesystem    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1     202G  145G   57G  72% /
```

But now we have a general way of doing this with any command.

Comment: Thanks. I knew bash could do this, I just wasn't sure how.